# How to center my current location in MKMapView?

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview

I am showing the `current location` in `MKMapView` by using `showUserLocation` enables. I also want to center the `mapview` to the user current location and also the zoomed map of location. Please help me regarding this as I don't get any help from other similar questions on stackoverflow.

My code is below:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  [mapView setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
  [mapView setZoomEnabled:YES];
  [mapView setScrollEnabled:YES];
  [mapView setCenterCoordinate:mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate animated:YES];
  [mapView setDelegate:self];
}
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

For centering on user location, you can use the following code:

```
[mapView setCenterCoordinate:mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate animated:YES];
```

For zooming on special locations, you should study how the regions (`MKCoordinateRegion`) are counted and work, count your values for the region and display it using call:

```
[mapView setRegion:myRegion animated:YES];
```

This [sample WorldCities](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/WorldCities/Listings/Classes_MapViewController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009466-Classes_MapViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_6) shows basics of region displaying.

Comment: i am also doint the same thing but it doesnot work....Any other suggestions if possible....thanks in advance...

Comment: maybe you can post your code in your question, so it will be easy to guess what's wrong =)

Comment: I have updated my code in question and this will not centered the mapView to currentLocation.Please check it and help me....thanks in advance.

Comment: if you're trying to set this from viewDidLoad: it will fail, because map view doesn't know yet the user location (it needs some time to receive response from GPS); so it will be correct to call [mapView setCenterCoordinate:mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate animated:YES] from the  UIMapViewDelegate method - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation

Comment: How do I add zoom in to user location?

Comment: i added profile pic on current location but it is not coming in center.

Comment: Swift 4: `mapView.setCenter(mapView.userLocation.coordinate, animated: true)`

Answer (score 2):

```
MKCoordinateRegion region;
    MKCoordinateSpan span;
    span.latitudeDelta = 0.2;     // 0.0 is min value u van provide for zooming
    span.longitudeDelta= 0.2;

    CLLocationCoordinate2D location = [self addressLocation];
    region.span=span;
    region.center =location;     // to locate to the center
    if(addAnnotation != nil) {
        [mapView removeAnnotation:addAnnotation];
        [addAnnotation release];
        addAnnotation = nil;
    }
    addAnnotation = [[AddressANnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:location];
    [mapView addAnnotation:addAnnotation];
    [mapView setRegion:region animated:TRUE];
    [mapView regionThatFits:region];
```

This had help me to show the position at the center of the map view.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void) removeZoom:(float)deltaValue
{
    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    region.center.latitude =  self.locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude;
    region.center.longitude = self.locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude;

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    region.span.latitudeDelta = deltaValue;
    region.span.longitudeDelta = deltaValue;
    region = [mapViewSelf regionThatFits:region];
    [mapViewSelf setRegion:region animated:YES];
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

Answer (score -1):

for MKMapView

```
self.mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
self.mapView.userTrackingMode = MKUserTrackingModeFollow;
```